# JavaFX hide form then show again instantly

Tags: java, javafx, java-8, javafx-8

I am working a calculator, and I want have a log stage opened on the side, now my problem is that I need to update the stage, I figured the easiest way would be to just check if the stage is showing, and if it is then hide it, that just doesn't seem to be working, here is my code:

```
    public void start(Stage logStage) {
    boolean open = logStage.isShowing();
    System.out.println(open);
    if(open == true){
        logStage.hide();
        System.out.println("Should be hidden now!");
    }

    logStage.setTitle("Log");
    GridPane grid = new GridPane();
    grid.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_CENTER);
    grid.setHgap(5);
    grid.setVgap(5);

    TextArea logText = new TextArea();

    for (String log : Logger.fraLog()) {
        logText.setText(logText.getText() + log);
    }

    grid.add(logText, 0, 0, 10, 10);

    Scene scene = new Scene(grid);
    logStage.setHeight(210);
    logStage.setWidth(300);
    logStage.setX(1135);
    logStage.setY(350);
    logStage.setScene(scene);
    logStage.setResizable(false);
    logStage.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
    logStage.show();
}
```

And after running this method 3 times my output is:

```
false
false
false
```

The way I call the method is:

```
Logger logger = new Logger();
logger.start(new Stage());
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Create a small toggle button at the top right of calculator that opens the log when pressed. Use a tooltip to explain what the button is. example: "open log", "close log". Check out my javafx calculator here. https://github.com/sedj601/CalculatorFx

Comment: It is not the call to `show()` that is creating a new window; it is the call to `new Stage()` that does that. The call to `show()` simply makes the window appear on the screen: if it is already showing it has no effect.

Comment: Why not just updating the textfield no matter if logger window is visible or not?

Comment: The problem is that I can't figure out how to "just" update the textarea from another class

Answer (score 2):

A new `Stage` is hidden until you show it. Since you're creating new `Stage`s every time, none of them is shown when you read the `showing` property.

Furthermore since you're calling `show()` for the `Stage` anyways, you undo any effects of the `hide()` call.

Probably you should reuse the same `Stage`/scene graph. Furthermore it's unclear what effect you expect from the `hide()` call since you're showing the window again; simply replacing the content without hiding the `Stage` would have the same effect.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to update the TextArea from another class, then pass a reference to it, e.g. in the constructor of the other class. This might look like:

a) You class:

```
public class MyClass {
   private TextArea textarea;

   public MyClass(TextArea t){
     this.textarea = t;
   }

   public void someMethodThatNeedsToLog(){
      this.textarea.appendText("the next log message ...");
   }
}
```

b) Your initialization code:

```
public void start(Stage logStage) {

// ...

TextArea logText = new TextArea();

MyClass instance = new MyClass(logText);

// ...
logStage.show();
```

Hope that helps ...

BTW: This is not a matter of JavaFX or UI Programming. You might want to have a look on principles of object oriented programming like "inversion of control", "dependency injection/constructor injection".